# Zoom pinça com photoswipe

Tags: javascript, jquery, mobile

Olá, estou utilizando um template que comprei em um site porém estou tendo dificuldades para implementar o Pinch Zoom nele...

Basicamente é o seguinte:

Eu tenho uma galeria

```
<ul class="gallery" id="Gallery">
                <li><a href="images/paginas/10.jpg" rel="external"><img src="images/paginas/10.jpg" alt=""/></a></li>
                <li><a href="images/paginas/11.jpg" rel="external"><img src="images/paginas/11.jpg" alt=""/></a></li>
                <li><a href="images/paginas/12.jpg" rel="external"><img src="images/paginas/12.jpg" alt=""/></a></li>
            </ul>
```

e esse é meu JS para instanciar o PhotoSwipe:

```
(function(window, PhotoSwipe){
            document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function(){
                var
                    options = {
                        loop: false
                    },
                    instance = PhotoSwipe.attach( window.document.querySelectorAll('#Gallery a'), options );
            }, false);
        }(window, window.Code.PhotoSwipe));
```

Ele carrega a galeria e funciona muito bem porém ele só da o zoom quando eu do um duplo clique na imagem. Gostaria que ele também funcionasse o pinch zoom vi no site photoswipe.com o exemplo dele funciona mas o código é muito grande e desorganizado da pagina então não consegui encontrar a solução.

Alguma ideia ?

OBS: o template veio com esse import no lugar do PhotoSwipe puro "code.photoswipe-3.0.4.min.js" sera que tem algo haver ?

Comment: Este codepen tem o problema que referes? -> http://codepen.io/dimsemenov/pen/gbadPv